# PHP - Why is this variable not working in this foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach

The $value prints correctly. The number(s) are correct for $value so I think that part is eliminated.

If I manually enter the actual numbers in `($value)->price` like `(10079)->price`, the function works fine and the last line `print_r ($price)` prints the number it supposed to.

For some reason $value is not working in the context of `$xml_price = $fetch_app->products($value)->price;` as the function returns nil for `$price`

```
foreach ($_SESSION['queueList'] as $value){
            //this prints the correct item(s) in 'queueList'
            print_r ($value);
            //this gets the node with the price info
            $xml_price = $fetch_app->products($value)->price;
            //this converts the simpleXML node to a string
            $price = ((string) $xml_price);
            //session var accumulates the item prices in cart
            $_SESSION['totalPrice'] += $price;
            print_r ($price);

        }
```

So why is the `$value` variable not working, but an actual number does, even though I have printed the `$value` and it shows the correct number? The number is a float by the way, not sure if that matters.

Comment: have you tried explicitly casting $value as an (int). It may be treating it as a string?

Comment: Also use `var_dump()` to see the actual variable type and content (extra fillers e.g.)

Comment: use `var_dump()` for debugging, not `print_r`. It shows more info about the variable, namely type and length, which might be the problem.

Comment: @pburgess yes I tried `$price = ((int) $xml_price);` same results

Comment: @michi the FetchApp API PHP library: http://www.fetchapp.com/

Comment: @fab hmm, interesting.. these are the results for `var_dump($value)` `string(5) "10081" 0string(5) "10080" 0` - not sure what that means.

Comment: @frankie You obviously misread my comment, I said to cast $value as an (int), exactly what the answer you accepted said ;) Perhaps I should have posted the line to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the additional information from the comments, the following should work:

```
$xml_price = $fetch_app->products((int)$value)->price;
```

It looks like this fetchapp API is strongly typed, which is untypical for PHP but still technically possible to a certain extent. At least it treats string parameters different from integer parameters.

Comment: this solved it for me `foreach ($_SESSION['queueList'] as $value){
  //this gets the node with the price info
  $xml_price = $fetch_app->products($value)->price;
  // convert the simpleXML node to a string
  $price = ((string) $xml_price) * 100;
  //session var accumulates the item prices in cart
  $_SESSION['totalPrice'] += $price;
    }
`